# UI is stuck in splash Screen in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, future, splash-screen

i am designing a splash screen for my application ...i want to show my splash screen for 3 seconds for which i am having a condition in a Future.delayed function in which i am checking whether user is logged in or not if he is logged in then i want to Navigate to the MainPage otherwise i want to navigate to the LoginPage.
But my UI is stuck in splash screen and my Future.delayed function is not compiling.

```
class Splash_Screen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _Splash_ScreenState createState() => _Splash_ScreenState();


  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      return Obx(() {
        return Get
            .find<FirebaseController>()
            .user != null ? MainPage() : LoginPage();
      });
    });
  }
}

class _Splash_ScreenState extends State<Splash_Screen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(0, 0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                AppColors.colorAccent,
                AppColors.colorPrimary,
              ],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/s_book_splash_logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For your kind information the initState() function was available only in statefull widget that's why i am using this stateful widget and i don't know it is right approach to call an Obx() method in a stateful widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this replace your code with this

splash_screen.dart

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  SplashController con = Get.put(SplashController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(0, 0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                AppColors.colorAccent,
                AppColors.colorPrimary,
              ],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/s_book_splash_logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

splash_controller.dart

-> Here i checked token available then navigate to MainPage() otherwise LoginPage()
-> You need to check your condition it will work

```
class SplashController extends GetxController {
  
  void _checkIfIsLogged() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((val) {
      LocalStorage.token.toString() != "null" && LocalStorage.token != ""
          ? MainPage()
          : LoginPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    _checkIfIsLogged();
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Comment: i am still facing the issue ... my SplashController is...

Comment: what you check in condition?

Comment: void _checkIfIsLogged() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), (){
      return Obx(() {
        return Get
            .find<FirebaseController>()
            .user != null ? MainPage() : LoginPage();
      });
    });
  }

Comment: obx not work here you check user login or not?

Comment: yes i am fetching an email of a curreloginn User and then i am checking it is he logged in or not

Comment: return Get.find<FirebaseController>().user means we are getting email of of user through FirebaseController ...with this line of code   get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email ;

Comment: You can check user login or not directly here

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid != null ? MainPage() : LoginPage();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241607/discussion-between-ravi-limbani-and-saad-ebad).

Comment: Have you guys solved this? I am builindg the app and sometimes the splash screen with Firebase call to get signed in user is very very slow.